# How to know which item is currently selected in the Combo Box Popup

Tags: wpf, combobox

How to know which item is currently selected in the Combo Box Popup. So that the Combo Box can be updated while the navigation happens inside the Popup.

*Note:* Need to update it though the Combo Box's popup is still open. Like the below image,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set [`IsEditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `True`for ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectedIndex="0">

    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Add selection changed Event handler for the ComboBox like,

```
this.comboBoxName.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBoxSelection_NOTHROW);
```

2) Event handler method implementation,

```
private void comboBoxSelection_NOTHROW(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
      {
            ///Business logic goes here
               CUSTOMER selectedItem = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as CUSTOMER;
               if (null != selectedUser)
               {
                    comboBoxName.SelectedItem = selectedItem.First();
               }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried with this solution? It doesn't work.. `SelectionChanged` will not be invoked while this happens.. Do not mislead the question instead of getting correct answer.